# Correct kotlin syntax for onErrorResume with two arguments

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

How to properly translate some java code like the following into Kotlin:

```
Mono mono = ...
Mono x = mono
    .onErrorResume(BadJOSEException.class,
        e->Mono.error(new RuntimeException()))
```

OnErrorResume comes from Spring Reactor and is defined as follows:

```
fun <T : Any, E : Throwable> Flux<T>.onErrorResume(exceptionType: KClass<E>, fallback: (E) -> Publisher<T>): Flux<T>
//Extension for Flux.onErrorResume providing a KClass based variant.
```

I tried several options, but all give compilation errors, and Intellij is also not helping out.
It works fine if I remove the first argument with the exception type, but I'm sure there should be a way to include the exception type so to restrict to certain types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```kotlin
val x = mono.onErrorResume(BadJOSEException::class) { Mono.error(RuntimeException()) }
```

Note, that this `onErrorResume` extension function is deprecated in `reactor-core`, to use it you need to add [reactor-kotlin-extensions](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kotlin-extensions) dependency

Comment: I didn't know it was deprecated, but in any case, adding the extra dependency did not help me.
I should have mentioned that rather then `{Mono.error(RuntimeException()}` I would like `{t -> Mono.error(...)}`  and Intellij tells me "Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly" for `t`. But when explicitly added, it tells me that no function can be found with given arguments.

Comment: Works with `{ t -> ... }` as well as with  `{ t: BadJOSEException -> ... }` for me. Maybe some glitch in IntelliJ? Does it compiles?

Comment: Thanks, I kind of figured it out.  I had to add `import reactor.core.publisher.onErrorResume`  and then it also becomes apparent that it is deprecated. Next step will be to try to come to a non-deprecated alternative

Comment: Bit silly on my side, got confused by the message in Intellij, but you are right. If you simply add the reactor kotlin extensions and you change the import to ``import reactor.kotlin.core.publisher.onErrorResume` then it works as expected.